# Break for-loop and swich-case at once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement

I wonder how to break a for-loop and switch-case statement **at once** in JavaScript?

Normally I use something like:

```
foo:
for(;;)
  for (;;)
      break foo;
```

Is there a way to do the same trick with a case at the beginning?

```
switch(1) {
  foo:
  case 1:
    for (;;)
      break foo;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do anything like that with a case, it's not the same. Use a function instead.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the switch instead?

Comment: I have a lot of cases and within the for-loop I try to find out if I should beak the whole case at once or should go on - there is a function which can be exectued AFTER the for-loop IF the for-loop didn't find any problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the label for the `switch` statement itself instead of one of the cases. The break will take you out of the `switch`, which I think is what you're trying to do.

```
foo:
switch(1) {
  case 1:
    for (;;)
      break foo;
}
```

Comment: The form `break foo;` is effectively a goto statement and can be used many places. You can only put the label on the front of a statement, though.

Answer (score 2):

label the `switch`

```
foo: switch(1) {
    case 1:
        while (1) break foo;
    case 2:
        console.log(2);
}
```

The loop breaks and `2` will never be logged.

Comment: You can label / break most blocks in JavaScript (e.g. `a:{console.log('hello'); break a; console.log('goodbye');};`). Just be sure not to confuse it with literal object notation.